# Google Checkout account registration error

Tags: android, in-app-billing, inappsettings

My client belongs to Norway and he wants to register Google Checkout account. I gave him this [**link**](http://checkout.google.com/seller/fees.html) for the registration,but he is getting error as "**You are apparently online through Google Checkout with a Google Apps account. Account Administrator may have access to financial data and other information in your Google Checkout account, or may suspend your access to this account.**" & "**You have sent a request invalid instrument**". Does anybody have any idea regarding this error or can let us know where we are lagging.Any kind of help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client will need to enable Checkout for their Apps account.

Here is a good blog post explaining how to do this:
http://googlesmb.blogspot.com/2010/12/now-available-with-google-apps-google_08.html